# docstring codeblock not showing properly in spyder 5.2.21

Tags: python, spyder, python-sphinx, docstring, numpydoc

I'm trying to comment my python function  that I have written, according to [sphinx](https://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/cheatsheet.html#making-a-list) and [numpy docstring](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html).

Spyder uses sphinx to render the docstring in the help window. When I see my docstring in window I Don't see title and other thing ....

```
    """
Génère deux graphes de type networkx le graphe de **Delaunay** et le graphe de **Laguerre**.
Ils sont générés à partir des coordonnées et à partir du rayon d'isolant de chaque fil contenus
dans un toron. Les données du toron sont au préalable renseignées dans l'objet ``obj_harness``.

Cet objet ``obj_harness`` est créé au préalable dans la fonction *import_data_solve()* contenu
dans *import_data.py*. Pour comprendre le fonctionnement de cet objet consultez dans le script
*tool_geom.py*, l'objet Harness et ses fonction *__init__* et *update_dict_from_wire()*.

Actuellement le rayon ``radius_ref_dmin`` est souvent déterminé très proche du rayon minimal.
En effet, lorsque ``radius_ref_dmin``>>radius_min, les angles de fils donnant sur cette limite
sont trop réduits pour une estimations correctes des déperditions thermiques vers l'extérieur.

**Attention** cette fonction ne permet que l'ajout des nodes pour les graphes de Delaunay et de
Laguerre. Pour ajouter les edges et les informations géométriques et thermiques à ces deux
graphes il faut les réinjecter dans la fonction *get_voronoi_cells()*. Les nodes de Delaunay
sont numérotés avec les ID correspondant aux ID fournis dans le fichier *data/db_TDL.json*
(fichier généré à partir de *sources/pseudo_TDL.xlsx*).

Dans chaque **node** du graphe de **Delaunay** est initialisé des datas à partir des
informations contenues dans l'objet harness. Ces informations seront utilisées dans la fonction
*get_voronoi_cells()* :
    * pos :
        coordonnées du centre du fil correspondant au node, coordonées en mètre,
        np.array([x, y]).
    * radius :
        le rayon extérieur du fil correspondant au node en mètre.
    * radius_core :
        le rayon de l'âme du fil (calculé à partir de la surface équivalente) en mètre.
    * weight_ins_tools :
        la résistance cylindrique de l'isolant exonérée de la surface correspondant au node.
        log(radius_ins/radius_core) / thermal_k
    * emissivity_ins :
        Emissivité radiative de la surface de l'isolant du fil correspondant au node.
    * Ang :
        initialisé vide. Sera complété par un dictionnaire contenant en clé les voisins et en
        value les angles correspondants vers ce voisin.
    * Dmin :
        initialisé vide. Sera complété par un dictionnaire contenant en clé les voisins et en
        value les distance minimal coupant le segment de Laguerre vers ce voisin.

Dans chaque edge du graphe de Delaunay est initialisé par défaut :
    * type_edge :
        à la valeur *intern*, cette valeur sera modifiée dans *get_voronoi_cells()* pour
        indentifier les edges périphériques et les edges qui relie la limite.

Dans chaque **node** du graphe de **Laguerre** est initialisé des datas à partir des
informations géométriques issues de la fonction *ConvexHull*. Ces informations seront utilisées
dans la fonction *get_voronoi_cells()* :
    * pos :
        coordonnées du centre de pondération entre 3 nodes de Delaunay (triangulation),
        coordonées en mètre, np.array([x, y]).
    * ccw_tri :
        liste des 3 ID des points de Delaunay correspondant à la triangulation de ce node de
        Laguerre, [int1, int2, int3].


Parameters
----------
obj_harness : Harness object
    Objet harness initialisé par import_data_solve() dans import_data.py.
radius_ref_dmin : float
    Les noeuds de Laguerre à l'extérieur de ce rayon sont supprimés, ainsi les edges de
    Delaunay correspondentes sont aussi supprimées. Ce rayon est en mètre [m].


Returns
-------
graph_del : nx.Digraph
    Graphe de Delaunay avec seulement les nodes de renseignés. Graphe Dirigés.
graph_lag : nx.Graph
    Graphe de Laguerre avec seulement les nodes de renseignés, les nodes à l'extérieur de
    radius_ref_dmin sont supprimés. Graphe non dirigés.


See Also
--------
get_voronoi_cells :
    Permet de completer les deux graphes avec chaques edges et de charger les informations
    utiles pour le calcul de resistances thermiques.
Harness :
    Définition de l'objet Harness dans le script tool_geom.py.

References
----------
```

.. [1](https://matplotlib.org/sampledoc/cheatsheet.html#making-a-list) Nocaj, A. and Brandes, U. (2012), Computing Voronoi Treemaps:
Faster, Simpler, and Resolution‐independent. Computer Graphics Forum,
31: 855-864. doi:10.1111/j.1467-8659.2012.03078.

.. [2](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html) Aurenhammer, F. (1987), Power Diagrams: Properties, Algorithms and
Applications. SIAM Journal on Computing 1987 16:1, 78-96.
doi.org/10.1137/0216006

```
.. Warning:: Il faut importer ConvexHull et networkx
>>> from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import numpy as np
"""
```

[docstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQB4v.png)

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. You have quite a long docstring. Please trim it down to a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.